# How to change specific row color to colomn value in jtable java

Tags: java, jtable

```
private void rangeActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
        try {
            if (fromdate.getDate() == null | todate.getDate() == null) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Date Range Is Not Set", "Warning!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            } else {
                Connection connection = DBConnect.getDbConnection();
                Date FromDate = fromdate.getDate();
                Date ToDate = todate.getDate();

                Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                String fromDate = formatter.format(FromDate);
                String toDate = formatter.format(ToDate);

                if (toDate.compareTo(fromDate) > 0) {

                    String Query = "SELECT id,requestDate,epfNumber,employeeName,department,requestText,responseText,type,severity,machineID FROM `inquiry` WHERE `requestDate` BETWEEN '" + fromDate + "' and '" + toDate + "' ORDER BY severity DESC ";

                    try (Statement smt = connection.createStatement(); ResultSet results = smt.executeQuery(Query)) {
                        ResultSetMetaData metaDt = results.getMetaData();

                        DefaultTableModel defaultTableModel = new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
                                new Object[][]{},
                                new String[]{
                                    "Inquiry ID", "Reported Date & Time", "EPF No", "Employee Name", "Department", "Incident", "Response", "Category", "Severity", "System Login",}
                        );

                        while (results.next()) {

                            Object[] itemRow = new Object[]{
                                results.getString(1),
                                results.getString(2),
                                results.getString(3),
                                results.getString(4),
                                results.getString(5),
                                results.getString(6),
                                results.getString(7),
                                results.getString(8),
                                results.getString(9),
                                results.getString(10),};
                            defaultTableModel.addRow(itemRow);

                        }
                        REPORT.setModel(defaultTableModel);
                    }
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Date Range Is Not Correct", "ERROR", 2);
                }

            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e);

        }
    }
```

this is my java code for puttint data from db to a jtable, I need to change the color of specific row according to the values that I get from "Category" column, for an example if Category is critical all the rows row color that containing that column value must change to red,

Please help !